# How can I make a payara netbeans integration

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans-plugins, netbeans-8, glassfish-4.1

How can I make a payara netbeans integration, it is posible? How I can integrate Payara with netbeans,
what can you tell me about the integration, there is a plugin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should just be able to add it as a GlassFish Server.

When Payara 4.1.151 was first released it didn't work with the GlassFish plugin in NetBeans, though this has now been fixed; you may need to re-download Payara to ensure you have the re-released version which will work with NetBeans.

Alternatively, you can rename the *console-core-4.1.151.jar* file to *console-core-4.1.jar*, which is what was changed for the re-release. You can find this file in this directory: *payara41/glassfish/lib/install/applications/__admingui/WEB-INF/lib*

Also make sure NetBeans is up to date (currently 8.0.2), as I don't believe it works with 8.0.0.

Comment: Adam Bien tried and verified the above here: http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/glassfish_became_the_killer_appserver

Answer (score 2):

Go to Tools → Servers.
Select GlassFish Server, and name the server whatever you want. For this example I've named it 'Payara 4.1.1.164', as that's the version I'm using. Click next.
Select the location of the 'payara41' directory from the extracted Payara Server. Read and accept the license agreement. Click next.
Select a domain. A domain is essentially a server at runtime. Unless you've created your own, use domain1 as it's the default domain. Enter 'admin' as the username and leave the password field blank.